# ESXi Second hard drive empty after failure ? or is it?

Tags: vmware-esxi, hard-drive

I had an esxi server installed on a 500GB drive. the system also had a 2TB drive.  I had put vm's on both drives.  The 500GB drive has failed.  When i attempt to connect the 2TB SATA drive to either Windows 7 or Ubuntu they both show the drive as empty.

I have installed vmfs-tools.  When i try to mount it, i get 'Unable to open device/file "/dev/sdc".

Using the disk utility, it shows up but shows as 2.0 TB Free.

I'm just not sure how a drive failure with the primary drive would make the second one blank.

```
using: vmfs-fuse /dev/sbd /mnt/vmfs gives this error:
VMFS VolInfo: invalid magic number 0x4e9052eb
VMFS: Unable to read volume information
```

thanks for any help

---

UPDATE:

So i installed new ESXi on a drive i had laying around. I plugged in the 2GB SATA drive and ESXi tells me its empty - HOW CAN THIS BE? Now i am just plain out - I will not use ESX anymore because of this - not sure how anything could have caused the primary drive to fail and completely erase the secondary drive - makes no sense!!!  I used to backup religiously, i only lost a few things (since much of the data was backed up) - but i lost a couple things i wish I hadnt :-(

Comment: Is the file system on both disks VMFS? Windows won't recognize a VMFS partition.

Comment: yea, I have tried on both linux and windows

Comment: Have you tried ESXi?  I wouldn't trust any other OS to tell me what's up with a VMFS disk, personally.

Comment: @Shane - i have not.  I guess i'll give that a try just to be sure.

Comment: So i installed new ESXi on a drive i had laying around.  I plugged in the 2GB SATA drive and ESXi tells me its empty - HOW CAN THIS BE?  Now i am just plain out - I will not use ESX anymore because of this - not sure how anything could have caused the primary drive to fail and completely erase the secondary drive - makes no sense!!!

Answer (score 0):

I notice you say /dev/sbd.  I suspect this is a typo of /dev/sdb.  However, even so, normally the VMFS resides on a partition on the volume (formatting an entire HDD with no partition table is very unusual).  ESXi 5 generally uses GPT, so make sure you are using a linux distribution that supports it (as well as the FUSE VMFS implementation), and mount just the partition.  You should find your VMs there.

If that doesn't work, make sure (using gparted) that there are actually partitions on the device.  If not, you may be doomed.

Good luck!